# django upload multilple files fields not save

Tags: django

I am trying to upload multiple files but somehow other fields are saved, only the files that were uploaded were saved. I don't know what I did wrong.

```html
def company_form(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = CompanyFrom(request.POST, request.FILES)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('Supporting_Documents')
        if form.is_valid():
             for f in files:
                 file_instance = InternationalCompany(Supporting_Documents=f)
                 file_instance.save()
           
            messages.info(request, 'Record was successfully added to the database!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/company_form')
    else:
        form = CompanyFrom()

    return render(request, 'company_form.html', locals())
```

```html
class InternationalCompany(models.Model):
    International_company_Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    International_company_Id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    options = (
        ('Yes', 'Yes'),
        ('No', 'No'),
    )
    Does_it_have_a_Financial_Dealers_License = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=options, null=True)
    Register_Office = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True)
    Beneficial_owner = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    Beneficial_owner_id = models.FileField(upload_to='passport/pdf/',null=True)
    Supporting_Documents = models.FileField(upload_to='support_doc/pdf/', null=True)
    expire_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    BO_Phone_number = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    BO_Email_Address = models.EmailField(null=True)
    BO_Residential_Address = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.International_company_Name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think I understood correctly your problem but, maybe the problem is that you are creating new instances with each file and not saving the form.

```
def company_form(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = CompanyFrom(request.POST, request.FILES)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('Supporting_Documents')
        if form.is_valid():
            #add this line to save the form
            company = form.save()
            #Here you are creating a new Company object for each file
            #just with de Supporting_documents field
            for f in files:                    
                file_instance = InternationalCompany(Supporting_Documents=f)
                file_instance.save()                                      
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/company_form')
    else:
        form = CompanyFrom()

return render(request, 'company_form.html', locals())
```

Then if want you want is to associate the file with de company, just do this instead:

```
if form.is_valid():       
    company = form.save(commit=False)                
    for f in files:                    
        company.Supporting_Documents = f
    company.save()                                             
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/company_form')
```

If you want a company to have multiple files, you have to change your aproach, because your Supporing_Documents field, only accepts one. Maybe with a M2M relationship.

I hope it helps in some way.